# Wizard control not retaining state between steps

Tags: asp.net, wizard

I have a wizard control and in one of the steps, I dynamically build a table.  If I move forward to the next step and decide to return back to the step with the table, the table is destroyed and only the header row is there.  I set up some test scenarios and the bottom line is that when you leave the step, the table is wiped out.

I have view state enabled and set to true.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the problem is dynamically created table. May be you have to create the table on every postback

Comment: I did some more testing and the table is gone even in the step deactivate event.  The problem is that there are drop down list boxes in the table and I need to capture those values.  But the table is gone by the time any event fires for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved....disable view state.